# nvd3 Line Chart Not Drawing w/ Correct Data

Tags: javascript, meteor, charts, nvd3.js

I'm currently trying to render an nvd3 Line Chart in Meteor JS. I'm running Meteor 1.1.0.3 and running the nvd3 package on version 1.7.1.

Using the examples on the nvd3: http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html, I got the following code. However, even with correctly following the example, the graph draws but the dates are all 12/31/1969 and the y axis generates -1, 0, and 1 values. See the attached image:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .margin({ left: 25 })
        .showLegend(true)
        .showXAxis(true)
        .showYAxis(true);

    chart.xAxis
        .axisLabel('Date')
        .tickFormat(function(d) { 
            return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d));
        });

    chart.yAxis
        .axisLabel('Data')
        .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

    d3.select('#data-chart svg').datum(formattedData).call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});

formattedData = [
{
    key: 'Data', //key  - the name of the series.
    values: [{ date: 1439963723311, total: 3}, { date: 1441283002275, total: 1}, { date: 1441194849210, total: 2}], //values - represents the array of {x,y} data points
    color: '#ff0000' //color - optional: choose your own line color.
}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell D3 how to access the data—what is x and what is y.

(The example on the NVD3 site already has the keys as 'x' and 'y')

Try adding the accessor functions:

```
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .x(function (d) { return d.date })
        .y(function (d) { return d.total })
```

and if you want to make sure the y-axis starts at 0, include

```
        .forceY([0]);
```

Also, you need to make sure to sort your data beforehand (the last two items are out of order).

See this Plunk for a live example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QjcEXIIQ5aIhuFhpRwsj?p=preview

Comment: perfect! I also tried a different way where I completely replaced "date" with "x" and "total" with "y" and it worked.

one last additional question - how do you format the ticks so it's 1 date per tick? right now, it's rendering with 2 day intervals ("8/19/15 - 8/21/15" etc).

thanks again.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967173/how-to-make-xaxis-hourly-tickslike-0-1-2-23-in-stackedarechart-use-nvd3-js/30066232#30066232

Comment: @Lucus this would be a sufficient answer but the format of the date is only populated into the data array if it has a value other than 0 in it's corresponding "total" key. this means that if there was 3 total on 9/7/15, 0 on 9/8/15, and 2 on 9/9/15 - it skips the 9/8 and only populates the other 2 on the graph. is there a JS / nvs3 way to populate missing dates with a default value of 0?